# Put background image over text?

Tags: css

This is not the apparently-common question about how to put text over a background image.

I have a background image that I want to work as an overlay -- it should be over the text. For simplicity sake, placing another div over the existing div and giving that the background image is much more difficult.

Is it possible for a background image to be above the text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is definitely not possible, and rightfully so. It would be wrong (and confusing) if you could use the **background** property of an element for anything other than the **background**.

The right way to do this is with an absolutely positioned div (with width and height set to 100%) within the container, alongside the text: http://jsfiddle.net/EvqNb/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think if it's possible. For complicated designs, complicated approaches should be used. It's not possible to make MSN's first page in just one `div`. Anyways, as a workaround you can set `color` property of that div to `transparent`, it makes the text invisible but it's there in front of the background.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
<div class="container" style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;"> 
<p>Test to hide</p>
<div class="overlay" style="position:absolute;z-index:999;background:url(yourimage.jpg); width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understood the question, I think `{text-indent: -9999px;}` would help.

Comment: Hi Deividas,

Not trying to hide the text. The background image had transparency but didn't want the text selected, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem fairly easily by making the text transparent and setting the display mode to `inline-block`. Note that you need to know the exact size of your image if you want to display exactly your image:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #mydiv {
      width: 50px; /* The width of your image in pixels. */
      height: 50px; /* The height of your image in pixels. */
      display: inline-block; /* The inside needs to be a block to set it's size.
                                If positioned, it could be block as well. */
      color: transparent; /* Ensures we don't see the text. */
      background: url('logo.png'); /* The actual image we want to use. */
      overflow: hidden; /* Ensures that any text will not spill out of our box. */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mydiv">Example.com</div>
</body>
</html>
```