# Transparant PNG before text CSS

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to make a page without the opacity css stuff, but with a transparant image over all the text and images. Only, i can't get the background over the text.

CSS:

```
   background-image: url('spotlight.png');
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 100;
```

And HTML simple:

```
<div class="darkLayer"></div>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Thanks!

Comment: Check the link. This may be what you where looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314687/put-background-image-over-text

Comment: That's very interesting. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the png overlay over **everything** in the page, you need to have your overlay div empty of all content, and increase z-index to something like 20000 or whatever.

Although, I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do.

But it does beat css in terms of cross-browser compatiblity, I think.

Yes, **use quotation marks on your image url**.

Comment: Quotes aren't actually required.

Comment: It works now, on another way. I was just trying to make a mouse following spotlight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The url should be `url('spotlight.png');` and of course the png have to be transparent. I also suggest toninoj's idea with the high number z-index.
Anyway. Why do you want to do this? The only explanation I can guess is for making right click resist web pages, but there are other better way for reaching that goal.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8rkT/

In this example you'd just replace the background/opacity lines with your transparent background image.

---

```
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla gravida, metus pharetra euismod eleifend, nisi est tempor massa, vel consectetur lorem elit non ante. Nulla facilisi. Nulla id libero eu erat suscipit pellentesque ultrices quis tellus. Donec ante dui, scelerisque nec venenatis id, suscipit sit amet ligula. Nulla turpis justo, fermentum id ullamcorper condimentum, posuere sit amet ligula. Praesent auctor, mi at tempor tincidunt, felis libero pretium ipsum, quis iaculis odio erat eu urna. Integer vel fermentum ipsum. Duis sit amet accumsan nunc. Nulla facilisi. Etiam condimentum nulla nec quam venenatis laoreet. Etiam massa ipsum, pellentesque sed imperdiet eget, ornare eget est. Fusce pulvinar lorem in nunc tempus fringilla. Vivamus posuere augue a mi interdum rhoncus. </p>
</div>

<div class="overlay"></div>


 html, body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
}

.overlay {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:#333;
 opacity:0.75;
}
```