# How to replace HTML text with images using CSS content cross browser

Tags: html, css, css-content

So I have a navigation menu that is generated by my CMS:

[image]

The menu's HTML is straightforward (edited for clarity):

```
 <ul>
     <li><a href="...">Journal</a></li>
     <li><a href="...">Art</a></li>
     <li><a href="...">Work</a></li>
   </ul>
```

I want the items to show up as hand-written text, in keeping with the general theme of the site, using separate PNG files for each menu item.

To do that, I used the CSS `content` property like so:

```
#headerNav .nav li a[href="/_site/en/journal/"]  
 { content: url(/path/to/image.png); }
```

And it worked great! The HTML text of each item was replaced by the correct image:

[image]

However, alas, then I learned not every browser supports the  `content` property on selectors other than `:before` and `:after`! Chrome and Safari do it, but Firefox doesn. However when I *use* `:before`, the HTML node isn't replaced, but the image is added:

[image]

How do I work around this?

What didn't work:

- Making the `<a>` element `display: none` removed the `:before` part as well.
- Making the `<a>` element `position: absolute` and moving it elsewhere won't work either.
- Making the `<a>` element `width: 0px` screws up the layout because the images added through `content` aren't in the document flow.

What I don't want to do:

- Of course I can output the images by hand but I want to work with the HTML the CMS is giving me, which is `<li>`s with text in them.
- Any solution involving `background-image` would require me to specify each item's width and height in the style sheet, which I would like to avoid for the purposes of this question.
- Turning the handwriting into a font is not an option.
- Using JavaScript to replace the items on the fly is not an option. This needs to work using pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: [CSS image replacement is a well-documented technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/).

Comment: @Blazemonger none of the examples have all green

Comment: @Blazemonger to use any of them, I'd have to specify a width and height for each item manually in the style sheet, which I'd like to avoid - that's why I used `content` in the first place. (It's a fair compromise, though, if nothing else comes up, thanks for the reminder.)

Comment: @mplungjan That page is years old, too. Modern browsers weren't at the time. The last example [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/) was used in HTML5Boilerplate until December 2012.

Comment: I don't think there's *any* way to do CSS image replacement without specifying dimensions, except possibly using `:before` or `:after`.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314687/put-background-image-over-text with the image generated on the server from the url of the link?

Comment: What you really seem to want in this question is not an image replacement but a web font. Is there not a suitable one for your needs?

Comment: About the background image solutions, you can use background-size:100% 100%; to use them with dynamic sizes

Comment: @Blazemonger nope, it's a very specific handwriting. I will probably end up using one of the techniques you link to, but the `content()` approach is unique because you don't have to specify each image's size and I'd be interested to know whether it has a solution.

Comment: @derylius but then the background image would follow the element's size and not the other way round. You still have to specify a size for each element, you can't tell an element to assume the size of its background image

Comment: I guess you can have a fixed height on the li or a tag elements ? http://jsfiddle.net/z5NJQ/

Comment: thats true but I assumed you want them the same size of the text to not brake the layout so you just set the text invisible and you are good to go.

Comment: I might do it like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6jYCy/.

Comment: @Danko ha! That actually solves it: giving the `:before` a `display: block` and the link a fixed height. I suppose what happens is that the link text is pushed down, outside the viewport, by the image. It's hackish, but it's the answer to my question, so do write it out as one and I'll accept it!

Comment: @thirtydot that is a great technique as well. I can't add a span in the CMS's output without implementing a custom module (which I'd like to avoid) so I'll accept Danko's answer but please make your approach an answer for future visitors - it'll have my upvote

Comment: Probably a silly question, but since your images are text-based have you tried using `@font-face`? MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face, CSS-tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: @James I thought about it, but it would require building a font out of the handwriting, which is a *huge* task when done right (proper kerning, pairing, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are doing this into a navigation bar you should have a fixed `height` making the next method possible to work:

- First insert the image as `content` on the `:before` element and make it `display:block` to push the actual text of the `a` tag below.

  ```
  li a:before {
     content:url(http://design.jchar.com/font/h_1.gif);
     display:block;
  }
  ```
- Then hide that text with a fixed `height` on your `a` tag:

  ```
  li a{
     height:50px;
     overflow:hidden;
  }
  ```

The **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5NJQ/)**

Answer (score 2):

Answer was answered before OP added the line

> Any solution involving `background-image` would require me to specify
>   each item's `width` and `height` in the style sheet, which I would like to
>   avoid for the purposes of this question.

So if anyone interested in `background-image` solution can refer this, else can simply skip.

---

Am not sure how optimum solution I am suggesting is, but surely you can use `background-image` for each `a` element, using `nth-` pseudo, and set the fonts `color` to transparent, or use `text-indent` property with `overflow: hidden;`

So it will be something like

```
nav ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li:nth-of-type(1) a {
   background-image: url(#);
   display: block;
   width: /* Whatever */ ;
   color: transparent;
   text-indent: -9999px; /* Optional */
   overflow: hidden;
   font-size: 0; /* Optional, some people are really sarcastic for this */

   /* Below properties will be applicable if you are going for sprite methods */
   background-position: /* Depends */ ;
   background-size: /* If required */ ;
}
```

---

The reason why I would suggest you is :-

**Advantages :**

- Cross browser compatible
- Can you sprite methods to cut down http requests to request image for each tab
- Also, you are not losing the text which is between the `a` tags, which is really good as far as screen readers are concerned.

**Disadvantages :**

- Set custom `width` for each

---

Note: If you are going for a sprite solution, than `background-position` is anyways a must property to be used, so be sure you check out the support table first, before opting the sprite method.

[image]

<sup>[Credits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) - For support table</sup>

Comment: I edited, making it clearer why I would like to avoid that. It's a fair way out, though, if no other way comes up.

Comment: Fair points all, and I didn't think about spriting. I'm going to accept this unless anything else comes up in the next day.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, take your time, but what you are trying here, is I feel lil cheesy, stick with standard methods... :)

Comment: I think the method is pretty good for this specific kind of problem - if just it were supported by all browsers...

Comment: Danko came up with a solution in the comments. I'm going to accept that one when he posts it because it's the *exact* answer to my question, but your points about the advantages of using a background image are well taken and I will probably transition to that in the long run.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, that looks fine to me as well :)

Comment: I will go with this solution too if the need and is possible to manage Sprite Images

Answer (score 0):

I would put PNG images into `img` tag and then set `alt` attribute.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="..." title="Journal"><img src="journal.png" alt="Journal"/></a></li>
<li><a href="..." title="Art"><img src="art.png" alt="Art"/></a></li>
<li><a href="..." title="Work"><img src="work.png" alt="Work"/></a></li>
</ul>
```