# How can I apply a fore-ground css stylling rather than a back-ground stylling to text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some text in HTML lets assume inside a `<p>` Element,
and I want to add some color for example rgba(0,0,0,0.1) but 
`above` or else `on-top` of the text and not `below` or else 
`behind` the text.

**Question**: How can I achieve that? ( Feel free to answer using both css or javascript if needed ).

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts,
Periklis

Comment: Post what have you tried to do so far, and your desired output.

Comment: Hello @Zakk, Umm well I dont know how to approach this thus I have no code to share. That is why I came here for help. But all in all, I just want to have an element of any type overlapped with a layer of rgba(0,0,0,0.1) as color.

Comment: Can you post a sample output?

Comment: when you are putting "on top" the color do you mean preventing certain text from being visible with a solid background instead?

Comment: @mrtechtroid, Yes! By the term "on top" imagine you have a biscuit and that biscuit is your text. Now I want to poor some chocolate over that biscuit to cover it and that chocolate is the color.

Comment: Else you could think of this as a `foreground-color` parameter in css, where alternatively to the `background-color` parameter which draws colors behind the text, the `foreground-color` does it in the front of the text.

Comment: Post some image with what you mean as there are several ways to interpret your question. Don't make us guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stated In This Question [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314687/put-background-image-over-text) This Is Not Possible Natively With CSS. But We Can Have A Work Around For This And Here's How You Do It.

```html
<p>Here is the random paragraph. Here <span style = "color:transparent;background-color:blue;">You Cannot Read Me</span> But You Can Read Me.</p>
```

This Is Done By Removing The color Of The text and adding A background color. Also you can replace the background to a image if you want.

Comment: Hello @mrtechtroid, Umm well I dont want the text to dissapear thus I am using the `rgba(0,0,0,0.1)` which is a very low opacity extension of the `#000` aka `black color` to just cover the text but still be able to read it.

Comment: @JameuLukasli1 What about `<p>While this is <span style = "color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);background-color:white;">difficult to read,</span> this is very clear.</p>`?